# Dropdown the select box automatically

Tags: jquery

I am developing asp.Net page which has a `button` and a `select`.  I want to drop down the select element when i click the button control

Is it possible?

Comment: use a `label` instead?

Comment: can you able to send code?

Comment: Ah a label doesn't actually open the drop down, [just focuses on it](http://jsfiddle.net/3yvhp32x/) - you may need some sort of js library to do it.  [Check out this question and anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989458/select2-open-dropdown-on-focus)